# How to add an image inside a dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dynamic div inside my javascript with the following code:

```
 var div = $('<div id="a1"></div>').html("<font color=green>This is demo</font>");
```

I want to add an image above this text inside the dynamically created div but i am not getting how to achieve it.

I am creating dynamic divs using a for loop and want to add images at the same time in it.

```
for(var i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        //alert("Title for zeroth manual is: "+result.manuals[i].title);
        var div = $('<div id="a1"></div>').html("<font color=green>This is demo..</font>"); 
        $('#a1').prepend("<img src='iphone.png' />");
        $('#data').append(div);
    }
```

How can i do it? Please help.

Comment: Actually, I want to use the "div" variable name to insert the image. I tried with append but not getting the expected result. I did this to add the text inside a secondary div:    $('#data').append(div);

Comment: Does that selector works  $('<div id="a1"></div>'), I thought it shud b  $('#a1'). Its new to me.

Comment: I tried this Neeraj. Didnt work.

Comment: Create different ids id="a'+ i+'"

Comment: Don't use `font ` tags, they've been deprecated since HTML4. Use `span ` or `div` elements instead, with class-names, or, at worst, an inline `style` attribute to style the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this and its working fine for me.

```js
var elem = document.createElement("img");
      elem.setAttribute("src", "http://img.zohostatic.com/discussions/v1/images/defaultPhoto.png");
      elem.setAttribute("height", "30");
      elem.setAttribute("width", "30");
      document.getElementById("maindiv").appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var div = $('<div id="a1"></div>');
div.html("<font color=green>This is demo</font>");
div.prepend('<img src="...">');
```

Comment: This works for a single div but when I tried to create div with loop, it is inserting the images in one div only. I will share that code.

Comment: @AppleBud To create a multiple divs with the same ID is a very bad idea. Also this is not part of your Question.

Comment: @AppleBud You need to insert your DIVs inside the document at one point.

Comment: And as Peter said please use different ids for the div's to give the DOM a fair idea to append and prepend the html and images

Comment: Thanks for  your suggestions. Will definitely implement that in my code.

Answer (score 0):

**(Edited for the edit of the question)**

You can simply add it to the `html`:

```
for(var I = 0; I < size; I++) {
    //alert("Title for zeroth manual is: "+result.manuals[I].title);
    var div = $('<div id="a'+ I + '"></div>').html('<img src="iphone.png" /><font color="green">This is demo..</font>'); 
    $('#data').append(div);
}
```

You need different ids for your divs (the id is now a1, a2, ...)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
var div = $('<div/>',{id:"a1"});
$("<font/>",{color:"green"}).html("This is demo").appendTo(div);
div.prepend('<img/>',{src:"test.jpg"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = $('<div id="a1"></div>').html("<img src='iphone.png' /><font color=green>This is demo</font>");

$('#test').append(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

try -

```
for( var i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    var fontObj = $( '<font color=green>This is demo..</font>' );
    var imgObj = $( '<img src=".."/>' );

    var divToInsert = $( '<div id="a' + i + '"/>' );

    imgObj.appendTo( divToInsert );
    fontObj.appendTo( divToInsert );

    $('#data').append( divToInsert  );
}
```

hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone!

Adding an image in dynamically generated div using Vanilla JS -

You can use either backgroundImage property if you want to add an image to the div, or add an img tag in the div.

Using backgroundImage Property :

```
function myFunction(){
  //create a div element
  let cross = document.createElement("div");

  //add required properties
  cross.style.height="200px";
  cross.style.width="200px";
  cross.style.backgroundImage = "url('your_image.png')";

  //append div as a child to body
  document.body.appendChild(cross);
}
```

Using an Image Tag:

```
function myFunction() {
      //create a div element
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      
      //create an image element
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      
      //add image src property
      img.src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/new-years-day- 
      2021-6753651837108820-law.gif";
      
      //append div as a child to body
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      
      //append image as a child to div
      div.appendChild(img);
    }
```

I prefer using second approach, as you will have much control over stylings.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are referring to the div incorrectly.

try `$("div#a1").html....`

This is called selectors. Will be of use to read up on them.

Comment: The OP was creating a div not selecting one

Comment: @ChrisC thanks for the downvote. The OP stated he wanted to add to a div he had created, so in order to add to it, you first need to select it.