# how to add img to div dynamically

Tags: javascript

there is an array with data

```
let mapImages = [
        {way: 'C:/Users/djoni/Desktop/Lessons/document/Homework_document/Images/1.jfif',
                         description: 'picher  1'},
        {way: 'C:/Users/djoni/Desktop/Lessons/document/Homework_document/Images/2.jfif',
                    description: 'picher 2'},......]
```

there are several divS

```
<div class="mini">   </div>


        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
                   <img id ="pop" src ="" alt = ""  width="500" height="500" style="border: 2px solid red">
                    </div>
            </div>
```

i want my array pictures to be added to mini class div

```
function showImages() {
            document.body.innerHTML = "";
            for(let i = 0; i < mapImages.length; i++){
                document.body.innerHTML +=  ` <img src="${mapImages[i].way}" alt = "${mapImages[i].description}"  width="200" height="200" style="border: 2px solid red"> `;
            }
        }

        showImages();
```

the problem is that pictures delete everything else on the page, and are not added to the desired div (mini class).

Without use jquery or other frameworks

Comment: You're clearing and adding those images to `document.body`, not to div.

Comment: It is happening because you are adding your picture to `document.body`. Just add your picture to `document.querySelector('.mini')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an image inside a dynamically created div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222395/how-to-add-an-image-inside-a-dynamically-created-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearing the content of the *body* inside the function, so remove that. Also, you should update the content of the element with class *mini* instead of *body*:

```js
let mapImages = [
  {way:'C:/Users/djoni/Desktop/Lessons/document/Homework_document/Images/1.jfif',description: 'picher  1'},
  {way:'C:/Users/djoni/Desktop/Lessons/document/Homework_document/Images/2.jfif',description: 'picher 2'}
];

var miniClass = document.querySelector('.mini');
function showImages() {
  for(let i = 0; i < mapImages.length; i++){
    miniClass.innerHTML +=  ` <img src="${mapImages[i].way}" alt = "${mapImages[i].description}"  width="200" height="200" style="border: 2px solid red"> `;
  }
}

showImages();
```

```html
<div class="mini"></div>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id ="pop" src ="" alt = ""  width="500" height="500" style="border: 2px solid red">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (get the div using `getElementsByClassName` and add/append all your image tags)

```
function showImages() {
   let imgContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('mini')[0];

            for(let i = 0; i < mapImages.length; i++) {
               imgContainer.innerHTML +=  ` <img src="${mapImages[i].way}" alt = "${mapImages[i].description}"  width="200" height="200" style="border: 2px solid red"> `;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use id not class

```
<div id="mini">   </div>
```

and get it

```
document.getElementById('mini').innerHTML += ....
```