# How to draw an image in a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I was trying to draw an`img`in a canvas I tried everything but in the console it says `img is not a property` or something like that I don't remember so can anyone help?
Here's the js

```
function setupcanvas() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
  var c = canvas.getContext("2d")
  c.beginPath();
  var img = new image()
  img.src = "flappy_bird_bird.png"
  img.onload = function(){
    c.drawImage(img, 100, 100)
  }
}
```

Edit
Thx to mhkanfer "sorry if the name is wrong" I fixed it

Comment: Images in JavaScript aren't classes that you instantiate, they're DOM elements that you need to put in your HTML first then grab by a selector (i.e by id) I recommend reading this example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage

Comment: If you wish for your example to be all in JavaScript, then to append an image dynamically read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37003347/5757893. If you wish to access the image somewhere else, do not forget to set an id property for it to access it faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response using your first answer I referenced the image in html and hidden it with css and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were mostly right, though their are a couple of things:

1. Make sure `Image()` is capitalized
2. Make sure your image src file actually exists in that directory
3. And make sure your canvas has a width and height, if you haven't specified that anywhere, you canvas wont be shown

If you were to revise this, it would look something like:

```
function setupcanvas() {

  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
  var c = canvas.getContext("2d")

  canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;

  var img = new Image()
  img.src = "example.png"

  img.onload = function(){
    c.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  }

}
```